# Don't understand code submission error in text box.

Tags: discussion, javascript, design

I have been trying to submit my html and java script to help with the clarification of a question. I created the html and java script in notepad++, so i thought it was properly formatted. I even cleaned it up with jsbeautifier online and tried to submit it. I keep getting error message about 4 space indentation. I have pasted the code in this box and manually indented everything 4 spaces. Still unsuccessful. Am I missing something here?
Please help.

Comment: what error message are you getting exactly?

Comment: Questions about posting to SO belong on meta.

Comment: Paste your code into the question, mark it with the mouse, and use the `{}` tool to mark it as code. This will indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

First paste your code into the textbox, then select the code you want to indent, and
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. The combination will automatically indent your code.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to show your code in a questions is to paste it, highlight it and then click the {} curly brace button at the top of the text box.